# Issue about both results in agreement with 2 different ways to compute variance of a random variable : weighted chisquared vs Gamma distributions

Tags: r, density-function, gamma-distribution, convolution, chi-squared-distribution

1.) I am interested in computing the variance of this observable $O$ involving the coefficients of spherical harmonics $a_{\ell m}$ and the $C_{\ell}$ which is the variance of an $a_{\ell m}$ :

$$O=\sum_{\ell=\ell_{\min }}^{\ell_{\max }} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} a_{\ell m}^{2}$$

where $\left(a_{\ell m}\right)$, and $\left(\ell \in\{1, \cdots, N\},|m| \leq \ell\right)$, with $a_{\ell m} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, C_{\ell}\right)$ for each $|m| \leq \ell$ .

I recall the properties of a few basic distributions. I use $\sim$ to denote equality in distribution. We have :

1. $\mathcal{N}(0, C)^{2} \sim C \chi^{2}(1)=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}, 2 C\right)$,
2. $\langle\Gamma(k, \theta)\rangle=k \theta$ and $\operatorname{Var}(\Gamma(k, \theta))=k \theta^{2}$, and
3. $\sum_{i=1}^{N} \Gamma\left(k_{i}, \theta\right)=\Gamma\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} k_{i}, \theta\right)$ for independent summands.

2.) Distribution followed by tUsing points 1 and 3 again, we obtain :

$$
\sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell}\left(a_{\ell m}\right)^{2}=\sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} C_{\ell} \cdot\left(\frac{a_{\ell, m}}{\sqrt{C_{\ell}}}\right)^{2}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sim \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} C_{\ell} \operatorname{ChiSq}(1) \\
&\sim C_{\ell} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} \operatorname{ChiSq}(1) \\
&\sim C_{\ell} \operatorname{ChiSq}(2 \ell+1)
\end{aligned}
$$
$\sim C_{\ell} \operatorname{Gamma}((2 \ell+1) / 2,2)$
$\sim \operatorname{Gamma}\left((2 \ell+1) / 2,2 C_{\ell}\right)$,
We have taken the convention (shape,scale) parameters for Gamma distribution. Given the fact that we consider the random variable :
$$
\sum_{\ell=\ell_{\min }}^{\ell_{\max }} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} a_{\ell m}^{2}
$$
This sum of random variables $\sum_{\ell=\ell_{\min }}^{\ell_{\max }} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} a_{\ell m}^{2}$ follows a Moschopoulos distribution : it represents the sum of random variables each one following a Gamma distribution with different shape and scale parameters.

**Question 1)** Is this reasoning correct ? I mean, I don't know if I can write this step :

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sim \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} C_{\ell} \operatorname{ChiSq}(1) \\
&\sim C_{\ell} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} \operatorname{ChiSq}(1) \\
&\sim C_{\ell} \operatorname{ChiSq}(2 \ell+1)
\end{aligned}
$$

**Question 2) :**

In relationship of Question 1) above, to compute the variance of $O$, I have implemented 2 ways (or called 2 methods) (in R language) with nRed is a bin redshift (like an index of sample) :

```
# Weighted sum of Chi squared distribution
y3<-array(0,dim=c(nSample_var,nRed));
  for (i in 1:nRed) {
    for (j in 1:nRow) {
      # Try to summing all the random variable
      y3[,i] <- y3[,i] + Cl[j,i] * rchisq(nSample_var,df=L[j])
    }
  }
```

And another method using `coga` library (convolution of Gamma distribution, see https://github.com/ChaoranHu/coga ) :

```
y1 <- array(0, dim=c(nRow))
# y2 is the Cl assimilated to scale parameter

# (shape/rate) convention :
for (i in 1:nRed) {
  y3[,i] <- rcoga(nSample, y1, y2)
}
```

Both methods gives the quasi-same variance, mean and skewness (which is close to 0, so quasi-gaussianity).

What it disturbs me is the first method with weighted squared : how can I justify that sum of Chisquared distribution has a PDF equal to the sum of each Chisquared(1) distribution, weighted by $C_\ell$ ?

Clasically, when we add random variables, the PDF is the convolution of all these random variables, isn't it ?

If you look at the first code snippet, I simply add on $\ell$ the chisquared distribution.
So it seems weird that I get the same results than with `coga` function (convolution of Gamma distribution).

Where is the error for the second code snippet ? (if there is an error).

Any track/suggestion is welcome.

**UPDATE 1:**

I think this derivation below is wrong :

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell}\left(a_{\ell m}\right)^{2}&\sim \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} C_{\ell} \operatorname{ChiSq}(1) \\
&\sim C_{\ell} \sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} \operatorname{ChiSq}(1) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

I should write instead :

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell}\left(a_{\ell m}\right)^{2}&\sim C_{\ell}\sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell} \operatorname{ChiSq}(1) \\
&\sim C_{\ell} \operatorname{ChiSq}((2\ell+1) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Shouldn't I ?

But I have still doubts if I can write with `pdf` the probability density function of random variable $X$ (here $X=\sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell}\left(a_{\ell m}\right)^{2}$) :

$$C_\ell X \sim C_\ell\,\text{Distribution}(X)\quad(1)$$

with $\text{Distribution}(X)=\operatorname{ChiSq}((2\ell+1)$.

As you can see, it is not still very clear.

Any clarification is welcome.

**UPDATE 2:**

I think that `@J.Delaney` is perfectly right, $C_\ell X \sim C_\ell\,\text{Distribution}(X)$ doesn't make sense.

But once we are in the code and we want to generate sample, can we do like I did with `R language` :

```
     L <- 2*(array_l)+1
     nSample_var <- 100000
     y3<-array(0,dim=c(nSample_var))
     for (j in 1:nRow) {
       # Try to summing all the random variable       
       y3 <- y3 + Cl[j] * rchisq(nSample_var,df=L[j])  
     }
```

?

with `Cl[j]` $\equiv C_{\ell,j}$

As you can see, I perform an increment sum with $C_\ell$ in front of the function `rchisq` which is the $\chi^2$ function of distribution : is it a right way to compute samples for random variable $O$ ?

If someone could translate this coding part and a mathematical expression of how are done things from a distribution point of view, this would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your **question 1)** : the result is correct, although your notation is a bit sloppy. first you have:

$$a_{\ell m}^2 /C_{\ell} \sim \chi^2_1$$

By definition, a sum of $k$ *independent* $\chi^2_1$ random variables has a  $\chi^2_k$ distribution (notice the assumption of independence: you have to assume that the $a_{\ell m}$'s are independent) so indeed
$$ \sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell a_{\ell m}^2 /C_{\ell} \sim \chi^2_{2\ell +1}$$

Now if $X \sim \chi^2_{2\ell +1}=\Gamma(\ell+\frac{1}{2},2)$ then  $C_{\ell}X \sim \Gamma(\ell+\frac{1}{2},2C_{\ell})$ by the scaling property of the Gamma distribution, therefore

$$ \sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell a_{\ell m}^2 \sim \Gamma(\ell+\frac{1}{2},2C_{\ell})$$

as you derived.
as for  **question 2)** : you are interested in the variable

$$O = \sum_{\ell=\ell_{min}}^{\ell_{max}} Y_{\ell} $$

where $Y_{\ell} \sim \Gamma(\ell+\frac{1}{2},2C_{\ell})$. Since $O$ is a sum of independent Gamma random variables, it's *distribution* is indeed a convolution  of Gamma distribution. However you can *sample* that distribution by generating samples from the distributions of the $Y_{\ell}$'s and summing them. This is what you do in your first method

> What it disturbs me is the first method with weighted squared : how can I justify that sum of Chisquared distribution has a PDF equal to the sum of each Chisquared(1) distribution, weighted by $C_\ell$ ?

You are generating the $Y_{\ell}$'s using the $\chi^2_{2\ell +1}$ distribution since as we saw before scaling a  $\chi^2_{2\ell +1}$ random variable by a constant $C_\ell$ gives you the distribution of $Y_{\ell}$.

> If you look at the first code snippet, I simply add on ℓ the chisquared distribution. So it seems weird that I get the same results than with coga function (convolution of Gamma distribution).

In the second method you are using the `coga` library that can calculate the convolution of Gamma distributions, however again you are using it to *sample* the distribution and not actually calculate the pdf  (which you can do using the `pcoga` function). The simplest method to sample this distribution is probably just by generating the individual Gamma random variables and summing them, so there's a good chance that under the hood the `rcoga` function is doing exactly what you do in your first method.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and detailled answer. But just a last precision, if you look at my **UPDATE**, I still don't know if I can write from a general point of view : $$C_\ell X \sim C_\ell\,\text{Distribution}(X)\quad(1)$$ for an arbitray $\text{Distribution}(X)$ given. Best regards

Comment: it depends on what the expression "$C_\ell \text{Distribution}$" is supposed to mean. It's best however  to avoid it because it can cause confusion. For example if $X$ divided by a constant $c$ has a $\chi^2$ distribution, you should express is as  $X/c \sim \chi^2$ and **not**   $X \sim c\chi^2$, because it might not be clear what $c\chi^2$ is supposed to mean

Comment: Could you tale a look please at my **UPDATE 2** , I have just a problem of how express mathematically the algorithm that I have implemented to generate a sample of $O$ random variable. Best regards

Comment: It's not clear how you define `Cl[j,i]` and `L[j]` and why you need the double loop. You should be able to do it with a single loop with `y[,i] <- Cl[i] * rchisq(nSample_var,df=2*L[i]+1)` ,(and summing the rows of `y` at the end) , which corresponds to $Y = \sum C_\ell X_\ell$ with $X_\ell \sim \chi^2_{2\ell + 1}$

Comment: Sorry for the lack of precision : `Cl[j]` $\equiv C_{\ell,j}$ . If you could confirm this is good, I would be glad. Regards

Comment: There is no $C_{\ell,j}$ in your question, only $C_\ell$

Comment: exactly, I meant that all $\ell$ are contained in a vector and the element $j$-th of the vector corresponds to the value $\ell=\ell_j$

Comment: Ok I see! so the new code seems correct to me as long as `L[j]`=$2\ell_j + 1$

Comment: and `y[j]` should be just `y`

Comment: It is corrected, everything is fine now from my side. Best regards